# Ordinary differential equation objective question.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the ODE  $$y'=f(y(t)),y(0)=a\in\mathbb{R}$$ Where $$f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$$

Which of the following statements are necessarily true?

$A.$ There exist a continuous function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}$ such that the above problem does not have a solution in any neighbourhood of $0.$

$B.$ The problem has a unique solution for every $a\in\mathbb{R}$ where $f$ is lipscitz continuous.

$C.$ When $f$ is twice continuously differentiable, the maximal interval of existance for the above I.V.P. is $\mathbb{R}.$

$D.$ The  maximal interval of existance for the above problem is $\mathbb{R}$ when $f$ is bounded and continuously differentiable.

According to me $A$ is false by Picard existance theorem, and $B$ is true and for $C$ $y'=y^{2}$ is counterexample. I have no idea about option $D.$ Please help me to handle option $D.$ In answer key option $D$ is given correct. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would be nice if you would link to the earlier question that you are obviously aware of, and would write in more detail what you did not understand from the answer there.